# Python: Read SQL Server Data using Concurrent Future Process Pool

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am extremely new to have never used any sort of parallel processing methods. I want to read a huge amount of data (i.e. at least 2 million rows) from the SQL Server and want to use parallel processing to speed up the reading. Below is my attempt at the parallel processing using concurrent future process pool.

```
class DatabaseWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, connection_string, n, result_queue = []):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        stmt = "select distinct top %s * from dbo.KrishAnalyticsAllCalls" %(n)
        self.query = stmt
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def reading(self,x):
        return(x)

    def pooling(self):   
        t1 = time.time()
        con = pyodbc.connect(self.connection_string)
        curs = con.cursor()
        curs.execute(self.query)                  
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            print("Test1")
            future_to_read = {executor.submit(self.reading, row): row for row in curs.fetchall()}
            print("Test2")
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_read):
                print("Test3")
                read = future_to_read[future]
                try:
                    print("Test4")
                    self.result_queue.append(future.result())
                except:
                    print("Not working")
        print("\nTime take to grab this data is %s" %(time.time() - t1))   


df = DatabaseWorker(r'driver={SQL Server}; server=SPROD_RPT01; database=Reporting;', 2*10**7)
df.pooling()
```

I am not getting any output with my current implementation. `"Test1"` prints and that's it. Nothing else happens. I understood the various examples provided by concurrent future documents but I am unable to implement it here. I will highly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: You have specified a list as a default argument - I do Not know if that is your problem but you should read [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/2823755).  A search using `python mutable default argument` may have other useful results.

Comment: Why do you think the bottleneck is the number of local processes fetching data?